# Laravel HasMany returning true on empty() on PHP7 upgrade

Tags: laravel, php-7

We are migrating an older Laravel 4 app to PHP 7.  Currently this blade code returns false on PHP 5.6:

```
@if(empty($review->region->region_slug) || empty($review->city->city_slug) || empty($review->park->park_slug))
```

However, once we try to run this on PHP 7, it returns true.  I traced it back and found this returns true:

```
empty($review->region->region_slug)
```

HOWEVER, if I use that beforehand, it will then return false.  Example:

```
echo $review->region->region_slug;

echo empty($review->region->region_slug) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
```

The slug will be returned AND FALSE will be returned.

The review model has the relationship like so:

```
    public function region()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Region', 'cgr_region_id');
    }
```

Which appears to be correct.  I am at a loss here.

Comment: I bet this is a question for Taylor himself to answer.

Comment: `empty() return true if the variable is an empty string, false, array(), NULL, “0?, 0, and an unset variable.`

Comment: Use `isset()` instead `empty()` because `empty()` will return true even when the var is null

Comment: Also you dont need any method to check for null values, null in fact means false when comparing, so `@if(empty($review->region->region_slug))` is the same as `@if($review->region->region_slug)`

Comment: I can resolve the issue if I load the review eagerly:  So instead of Reviews::findOrFail($id);  I load it like: Reviews::with('region', 'city', 'park')->findOrFail($id);  This was never required before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by loading the object eagerly. So instead of:

```
Reviews::findOrFail($id);
```

I load it like:

```
Reviews::with('region', 'city', 'park')->findOrFail($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a result of the Eloquent Collection which has likely come a long way since Laravel 4.  Basically, the collection object is **not empty**, only the fillable collection properties are.  So, to fix this, you can simply call the `isEmpty()` method on the collection object and if it is truly empty, your ternary operation should work properly.

This should work:

```
echo ($review->region->region_slug)->isEmpty() ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
```

Cheers